# CakePHP : Show database view

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a view in my database and i want to show the value. but i confused how to call the name of view in my controller. i have made a model, but still i can't show the view. my view database’s name is Vtotaleks. Please help me T_T

here my controller

```
class HomesController extends AppController{
 var $uses = array(
'Vtotaleks',
'SiswaMonitoring',
'Siswa',
'AuthUser',
'PerusahaanOrder');

 public function index(){
$this->Lib->cekprivilege();
$totalEks = $this->Vtotaleks->find('all', array('cache' => true));
```

and this my model

```
<?php
class Vtotaleks extends AppModel
{
  public $usetable = 'vtotaleks'; }
```

and this my view

```
 <tbody>
                <?php  $totalEkstrainee=0;foreach($totalEks as $datatotalEks){
                    $totalEkstrainee+=$datatotalEks['Vtotalekstrainee']['siswa_total'];

                    ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $datatotalEks['Vtotalekstrainee']['city_name']?></td>
                  <td align="right"><strong><?php echo $datatotalEks['Vtotalekstrainee']['siswa_total']?></strong></td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
                <tr class="danger">
                  <td><em>Total</em></td>
                  <td align="right"><strong><?php echo $totalEkstrainee?></strong></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```

and here the error

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: totalEks [APP\View\Homes\index.ctp, line 142]
>   Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Homes\index.ctp, line 142]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line after query

```
$this->set(compact('totalEks'));
```